# Javascript client storage with the same persistence as a session cookie

Tags: javascript, session, encryption, browser-storage

I want to implement a client storage mechanism that is as persistent as a session cookie but with more storage capacity.

I am doing this by encrypting the data before storing it and saving the keys in a session cookie, when this session cookie is gone the data can not be restored. Data is stored in a permanent webStorage such as localStorage or IndexedDB. I'll just talk about the localStorage case here.

The reason I am asking for a code review is concerning the security of that storage. Is it possible that different tabs generate different browserSession keys? Can an IV-reuse happen if multiple tabs are open at the same time? Am I using the WebCryptoApi correctly? I am leaking the keys to the server, is this a serious security issue considering I am storing sensitive data? Is there a way for the keys NOT to be sent to the server?

The code is separated into 4 parts. The first two (cookies, conversions) are just here for completeness, the other two provide the functionality I am looking for.

1. cookies
2. conversions
3. browserSession: From here I manage keys and nonces that can be used in the browserSession. The name is not perfect, but this can be thought of as a keyChain.
4. browserSessionStorage: Using keys and nonces from browserSession, this implements a storage mechanism that is used similar to localStorage and sessionStorage

Ad 1) cookies:

```
let cookies = {
    set: function(name, value, options={}) {
        let cookie = name + "=" + value;
        for(let key in options) {
            if(key != 'secure') {
                cookie += ';' + key + '=' + options[key];
            } else if(options[key] == true) {
                cookie += ';' + key;
            }
        }
        document.cookie = cookie;
    }, get: function(name) {
        name = name + "=";
        for(let cookie of document.cookie.split(';')) {
            cookie = cookie.trimLeft();
            if(cookie.startsWith(name)) {
                return cookie.substring(name.length, cookie.length);
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }, delete: function(name, options={}) {
        if(typeof options != "object") {
            options = {};
        }
        options['max-age'] = 0;
        cookies.set(name, false, options);
    }, httpOnly: function(name) {
        let tmp = cookies.get(name);
        if(tmp !== undefined) {
            // this is not a httpOnly cookie
            return false;
        }

        // cookie not existing or httpOnly, check whatever it is by trying to write it
        cookies.set(name, "test");
        let value = cookies.get(name);
        if(value === undefined) {
            // this is a httpOnly cookie
            return true;
        } else {
            // not httpOnly, remove the cookie again
            cookies.delete(name);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ad 2) conversions:

```
function buffer2uint8Array(buffer) {
    return new Uint8Array(buffer);
}
function uint8Array2utf8(uint8Array) {
    return String.fromCharCode(...uint8Array);
}
function buffer2utf8(buffer) {
    let uint8Array = buffer2uint8Array(buffer);
    return uint8Array2utf8(uint8Array);
}
function utf82uint8Array(utf8) {
    return Uint8Array.from([...utf8].map(ch => ch.charCodeAt()))
}
function utf82base64(utf8) {
    return btoa(utf8);
}
function base642utf8(base64) {
    return atob(base64);
}
function uint8Array2base64(uint8Array) {
    let utf8 = uint8Array2utf8(uint8Array);
    return utf82base64(utf8);
}
function buffer2base64(buffer) {
    let uint8Array = buffer2uint8Array(buffer);
    let utf8 = uint8Array2utf8(uint8Array);
    return utf82base64(utf8);
}
function base642uint8Array(base64) {
    let utf8 = base642utf8(base64);
    return utf82uint8Array(utf8);
}

function uint16Array2utf16(uint16Array) {
    return String.fromCharCode(...uint16Array);
}
function uint8Array2utf16(uint8Array) {
    let uint16Array = new Uint16Array(uint8Array.buffer);
    return uint16Array2utf16(uint16Array);
}
function utf162uint16Array(utf16) {
    return Uint16Array.from([...utf16].map(ch => ch.charCodeAt()))
}
function utf162uint8Array(utf16) {
    let uint16Array = utf162uint16Array(utf16);
    return new Uint8Array(uint16Array.buffer);
}
```

Ad 3) browserSession:

```
// provides browserSession keys and nonces
// dependencies: 
// - conversions
// - cookies
let browserSession = (function() {
    class Counter {
        constructor(uint8Array) {
            this.uint8Array = uint8Array;
        }
        next() {
            let carry = true;
            for(let i = this.uint8Array.byteLength; i > 0; --i) {
                let index = i-1;
                let prev = this.uint8Array[index];
                this.uint8Array[index] += 1 * carry;
                carry = prev == 255 && this.uint8Array[index] == 0;
            }
            if(carry) {
                throw("IV overflow");
            }
            return this.uint8Array;
        }
    }
    
    let browserSession = {
        hasKey: function(keyName) {
            if(keyName === null || keyName === undefined) {
                throw([{"Invalid key name" : keyName }]);
            }

            let keys = cookies.get('browserSessionKeys');
            keys = keys ? JSON.parse(keys) : {};
            return keyName in keys;
        },
        key: function(keyName, keyByteLength, nonceByteLength) {
            if(keyName === null || keyName === undefined) {
                throw([{"invalid key name" : keyName }]);
            }

            let keys = cookies.get('browserSessionKeys');
            keys = keys ? JSON.parse(keys) : {};
            
            if(keyName in keys == false) {
                keys[keyName] = uint8Array2base64(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(keyByteLength)));
                cookies.set('browserSessionKeys', JSON.stringify(keys), {secure:true});
                
                let nonces = localStorage.getItem('browserSessionNonces');
                nonces = nonces ? JSON.parse(nonces) : {};
                nonces[keyName] = uint8Array2utf8(new Uint8Array(nonceByteLength));
                localStorage.setItem('browserSessionNonces', JSON.stringify(nonces));
            }
            
            return base642uint8Array(keys[keyName]);
        },
        nonce: function(keyName, nonceByteLength) {
            if(keyName === null || keyName === undefined) {
                throw([{"invalid key name" : keyName }]);
            }

            if(browserSession.hasKey(keyName) == false) {
                throw([{"key not initialized" : keyName }]);
            }
            
            let nonces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('browserSessionNonces'));
            let returnNonce = utf82uint8Array(nonces[keyName]);
            { // update nonce
                let nonce = new Counter(utf82uint8Array(nonces[keyName]));
                nonces[keyName] = uint8Array2utf8(nonce.next());
                localStorage.setItem('browserSessionNonces', JSON.stringify(nonces));
            }
            return returnNonce;
        },
    }
    return browserSession;
})();
if(cookies.get('browserSessionKeys') == null) {
    localStorage.removeItem('browserSessionNonces');
}
```

Ad 4) browserSessionStorage

```
// creates a browserSessionStorage that is accessible as long as the browserSession lasts
// the data is managed from localStorage
// dependencies: 
// - browserSession
// - conversions
let browserSessionStorage = (function() {
    let storagePrefix = 'browserSessionStorage.';
    function withPrefix(keyName) {
        let encoder = new TextEncoder();
        let decoder = new TextDecoder();
        return storagePrefix + decoder.decode(encoder.encode(keyName));
    }
    
    let browserSessionStorage = {
        removeItem: function(keyName) {
            keyName = withPrefix(keyName);
            localStorage.removeItem(keyName);
        },
        clear: function() {
            for(let key in localStorage) {
                if(key.startsWith(storagePrefix)) {
                    localStorage.removeItem(key);
                }
            }
        }, 
    };
    
    let keyByteLength = 256 / 8;
    let ivByteLength = 96 / 8;
    if(browserSession.hasKey('browserSessionStorageKey') == false) {
        browserSessionStorage.clear();
        // initialize key and nonce
        browserSession.key('browserSessionStorageKey', keyByteLength, ivByteLength);
    }
    let key = (function() {
        let key = null;
        return async function() {
            if(key == null) {
                let rawKey = browserSession.key('browserSessionStorageKey');
                key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
                    'raw', rawKey, 'AES-GCM', true, ['encrypt','decrypt']
                );
            }
            return key;
        }
    })();
    function nextIv() {
        return browserSession.nonce('browserSessionStorageKey');
    }
    

    browserSessionStorage.setItem = async function(keyName, keyValue) {
        keyName = withPrefix(keyName);
        // encrypt the encoded keyValue
        let encoded = new TextEncoder().encode(keyValue);

        let iv = nextIv();
        let encrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({
            name: "AES-GCM",
            iv: iv
        }, await key(), encoded);
        encrypted = new Uint8Array([ 
            ...iv, 
            ...new Uint8Array(encrypted) 
        ]);

        localStorage.setItem(keyName, uint8Array2utf8(encrypted));
    };
    browserSessionStorage.getItem = async function(keyName) {
        keyName = withPrefix(keyName);
        // item may not exist
        let value = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
        if(value != null) {
            // decryption
            let encrypted = utf82uint8Array(value);
            let iv = encrypted.subarray(0, ivByteLength);
            encrypted = encrypted.subarray(ivByteLength);
            let decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({
                name: "AES-GCM",
                iv: iv
            }, await key(), encrypted);

            value = new TextDecoder().decode(decrypted);
        }
        return value;
    };
    return browserSessionStorage;
})();
```